# Choose the non null column per row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with a table which has "Name", "FirstName", and "Surname" fields.

"Name" was used years ago but is still supported.

Today though the "FirstName" and "Surname" fields are used instead.

Here's what I'd like to do for my query on this table. If FirstName and/or Surname are not Null then I want them returned for the row, otherwise I want Name.

FirstName and Surname can be concatenated with a space between, giving just a single field in the returned result. Or maybe you have a better solution.

Thanks you!

Barry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by either using `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(Firstname + ' ' + Surname, Name)
FROM   ATable
```

or using `ISNULL`

```
SELECT ISNULL(Firstname + ' ' + Surname, Name)
FROM   ATable
```

---

If Firstname **or** Surname can be `NULL` and you want to return one of these, you would use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(Firstname + ' ' + Surname, Firstname, Surname, Name)
FROM   ATable
```

[COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> Returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN [FirstName] IS NULL OR [Surname] IS NULL THEN [Name]
       ELSE [FirstName] + ' ' + [Surname]
       END AS [Name]
  FROM MyTable
```